# Clipboard.js doesn't work with a tiny test

Tags: clipboard.js

I am faced with a little problem, I try to use clipboard.js, but it doesn't work even in my test. My html is as following, please tell me what I have done wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="test" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body content="text/html">
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-demo="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should â€” clipboard.js">Copy to clipboard</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to init clipboard js on your element. Add this to your page:

`<script>new ClipboardJS('.btn')</script>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="test" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body content="text/html">
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-demo="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should â€” clipboard.js">Copy to clipboard</button>
</body>
<script>new ClipboardJS('.btn');</script>
</html>
```